# setting guifont in GVIM for windows xp ineffective

Tags: windows, vim

Multiple part question on running gvim on windows xp.

1. I have a _vimrc file that does not want to take either one of my guifont settings below:

   set guifont=Monospace:h8

   set gfn=Monospace:h8
2. I do not have a _gvimrc file, as it seems to take all the other settings I have told it to take. Do I really need a _gvimrc configuration file?
3. When I do a split-screen, why does my syntax highlighting disappear on the new screen(s)? My first file will highlight fine.
4. Is there a comprehensive blog on how to configure gvim for windows xp? I have found a few 'how-tos' but they haven't really been all that helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: With regard to #2:
  * If you have properly installed GVIM, by default, it will not require you to use a _gvimrc file.
  * Note to developers who are forced to use Windows XP- and not so familiar with Windows XP- in active directory: if you guys are still having problems with seeing your _vimrc in effect, check with your system administrator. They may have defaulted your home directory to a server somewhere. I did not realize this until I saw that my command prompt went from my C drive default to a Z:\>, even though I supposedly had full administrative rights to my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I was using the wrong font. There are a certain number of fonts gvim does not take on Windows. I am using this setting:

```
set gfn=courier_new:h9
```

Thanks.